# Generic FPS movement controller with Xbox One controller support

Tags: c#, game, unity3d

I'm currently working on an FPS shooter game and I needed a generic movement controller that supported both keyboard *and* Xbox One controller input. My main goal in designing this controller was to address two common issues that occurred in previous FPS controllers I've designed, which are:

- Diagonal movement (strafing) caused the player to move about twice as fast when a keyboard setup was being used.
- Jumping in a setting with a low ceiling caused the player to 'stick' to said ceiling.

Here's the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

/// <summary>
/// This class is responsible for controlling the players movement.
/// </summary>
[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
public class CharacterMovementController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool UseController;
    public Vector3 JumpSpeed;
    public Vector3 GravitySpeed;
    public Vector2 MovementSpeed;
    public Vector2 CameraRotationSpeed;
    public Vector2 CameraRotationConstraints;

    public CharacterController CharacterController { get; set; }
    public Vector3 MovementVector { get; set; }
    public float VerticalRotation { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Rotate the player.
    /// </summary>
    public void Rotate()
    {
        if(this.UseController)
        {
            this.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Xbox Look X"), 0.0f) * this.CameraRotationSpeed.x * Time.deltaTime);
            this.VerticalRotation += Input.GetAxis("Xbox Look Y") * this.CameraRotationSpeed.y * Time.deltaTime;
            this.VerticalRotation = Mathf.Clamp(this.VerticalRotation, this.CameraRotationConstraints.x, this.CameraRotationConstraints.y);

            Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(
                -this.VerticalRotation,
                Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.y,
                Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.z
            );
        }

        else
        {
            this.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), 0.0f) * this.CameraRotationSpeed.x * Time.deltaTime);
            this.VerticalRotation += -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * this.CameraRotationSpeed.y * Time.deltaTime;
            this.VerticalRotation = Mathf.Clamp(this.VerticalRotation, this.CameraRotationConstraints.x, this.CameraRotationConstraints.y);

            Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(
                -this.VerticalRotation,
                Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.y,
                Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.z
            );
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Move the player.
    /// </summary>
    public void Move()
    {
        if(this.UseController)
        {
            this.MovementVector += Vector3.forward * Input.GetAxis("Xbox Forward / Backward") * this.MovementSpeed.y;
            this.MovementVector += Vector3.right * Input.GetAxis("Xbox Left / Right") * this.MovementSpeed.x;
            this.MovementVector = this.transform.rotation * this.MovementVector;
        }

        else
        {
            bool keyboardMovingForwardBackward = false;
            bool keyboardMovingLeftRight = false;

            if(Input.GetButton("Keyboard Forward"))
            {
                this.MovementVector -= this.transform.forward * this.MovementSpeed.y;
                keyboardMovingForwardBackward = true;
            }
            else if(Input.GetButton("Keyboard Backward"))
            {
                this.MovementVector += this.transform.forward * this.MovementSpeed.y;
                keyboardMovingForwardBackward = true;
            }

            if(Input.GetButton("Keyboard Left"))
            {
                this.MovementVector -= this.transform.right * this.MovementSpeed.x;
                keyboardMovingLeftRight = true;
            }
            else if(Input.GetButton("Keyboard Right"))
            {
                this.MovementVector += this.transform.right * this.MovementSpeed.x;
                keyboardMovingLeftRight = true;
            }

            if(keyboardMovingForwardBackward && keyboardMovingLeftRight)
            {
                this.MovementVector = new Vector3(
                    this.MovementVector.x * (1.0f / Mathf.Sqrt(2.0f)),
                    this.MovementVector.y,
                    this.MovementVector.z * (1.0f / Mathf.Sqrt(2.0f))
                );
            }
        }

        if(!this.CharacterController.isGrounded)
        {
            this.MovementVector += this.GravitySpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            this.MovementVector = new Vector3(this.MovementVector.x, 0.0f, this.MovementVector.z);
        }

        if(Input.GetButton("Xbox A") && this.CharacterController.isGrounded)
        {
            this.MovementVector += this.JumpSpeed;
        }

        RaycastHit upperGroundedRaycastHit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position, this.transform.up, out upperGroundedRaycastHit, (this.CharacterController.height / 2.0f) + 0.1f))
        {
            this.MovementVector = new Vector3(this.MovementVector.x, this.GravitySpeed.y, this.MovementVector.z);
        }

        this.CharacterController.Move(this.MovementVector * Time.deltaTime);
        this.MovementVector = new Vector3(0.0f, this.MovementVector.y, 0.0f);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update is called once per frame.
    /// </summary>
    public void Update()
    {
        this.Rotate();
        this.Move();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Start is called once.
    /// </summary>
    public void Start()
    {
        this.CharacterController = this.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }
}
```

Is there anything that can be improved? Are there any potential pitfalls or problems that can occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Rotate()

In this method the only difference between the `if` branches are the getting of the `X` and `Y` location. It would be enough to place getting these in the branches and therefor you could remove some of the duplicated code but it would be much better just assigning the `string`'s, which are needed, to two variables like so

```
var xKey = "Mouse X";
var yKey = "Mouse Y";
if(this.UseController)
{
    xKey = "Xbox Look X";
    yKey = "Xbox Look Y";
}
this.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0.0f, Input.GetAxis(xKey), 0.0f) * this.CameraRotationSpeed.x * Time.deltaTime);
this.VerticalRotation += Input.GetAxis(yKey) * this.CameraRotationSpeed.y * Time.deltaTime;
this.VerticalRotation = Mathf.Clamp(this.VerticalRotation, this.CameraRotationConstraints.x, this.CameraRotationConstraints.y);

Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(
    -this.VerticalRotation,
    Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.y,
    Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.z
    );
```